# How to add new field to codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to add new field on my model, but I can't do it. Can anyone help me?
**This my function on my model:**

```
public function get_item(){
    $default_language = setting_value('default_language');
    $query = $this->db->order_by('p.id','desc')
            ->select("p.* , c.name as item_name, a.name as category_name")
            ->join("content_to_" . $this->url ." c", "c.item_id = p.id" , "left")
            ->join("content_to_item_category a", "p.item_category_id = a.item_category_id" , "left")
            ->get_where($this->url ." p",array('c.language_id'=> $default_language,'a.language_id'=> $default_language, 'p.flag !=' => 3))->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: actually I have to add field on table

Comment: Do you want to add field with code?

Comment: Do you want to add a new column in DB or in a query which you mentioned above?

Comment: I want to add new field from database to my mvc, but still not work, wich would i do

Answer (score 0):

use database forge for this purpose.
Here is the documentation of [DB FORGE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html)

i hope this will work !